# PLSQL Table keeps mutating

Tags: plsql

I'm trying to figure out why my table keeps mutating even though I have already created another package to maintain in memory a copy of the rows in the `jobs` table.

This is my emp_pkg that handles all the code for the employee, i will only be adding the procedure that i'm using in this package so it will be short:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY emp_pkg
IS
    PROCEDURE SET_SALARY(pjobid jobs.job_id%type,
                        psal    jobs.min_salary%type)
    IS
    BEGIN
        
        FOR i IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
        LOOP
            UPDATE employees
                SET salary = psal
            WHERE job_id = pjobid;
        END LOOP;
    
    END SET_SALARY;
  
END emp_pkg;
```

Then I created a trigger on the jobs table that invokes the `set_salary` procedure on my `emp_pkg` package when the minimum salary in the jobs table is updated for a specified job id:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER upd_minsalary_trg
AFTER UPDATE OF min_salary ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.min_salary != old.min_salary)
BEGIN
    emp_pkg.set_salary(:old.job_id, :new.min_salary);
END upd_minsalary_trg;
/
```

Now, I tested it by running the code below with the following errors as expected:

```
UPDATE jobs
    SET min_salary = min_salary + 1000
WHERE job_id = 'IT_PROG';
--ORA-04091: table SQL_WLALHQOYXPNRGAIYBLVJOQTEB.JOBS is mutating, trigger/function may not see it
```

Now like I said before, to fix this i have created another package to maintain in memory a copy of the rows in the jobs table:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY jobs_pkg
IS

    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;

    PROCEDURE initialize
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
        LOOP
            jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    
    FUNCTION get_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        vmin_salary jobs.min_salary%type;
    BEGIN
        SELECT min_salary
        INTO vmin_salary
        FROM jobs
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
        
        RETURN vmin_salary;
    END get_minsalary;
    
    FUNCTION get_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS  vmax_salary jobs.max_salary%type;
    BEGIN
        SELECT max_salary
        INTO vmax_salary
        FROM jobs
        WHERE job_id =  jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
        
        RETURN vmax_salary;
    END get_maxsalary;
    
    PROCEDURE set_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmin_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET min_salary = pmin_salary
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
    END set_minsalary;
    
    PROCEDURE set_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmax_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET max_salary = pmax_salary
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
    END set_maxsalary;
    
END jobs_pkg;
```

Then I implemented another trigger for before inserting or updating on the jobs table that invoke my `jobs_pkg.initialize` procedure on the jobs package to ensure that the package state is current before the DML operations are performed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER init_jobpkg_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    jobs_pkg.initialize;
END init_jobpkg_trg;
```

Now the problem is when I tried to run the code below it still mutates:

```
UPDATE jobs
    SET min_salary = min_salary + 1000
WHERE job_id = 'IT_PROG';
```

I keep searching on why it still mutates but can't seem to find the problem.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It is mutating because you keep trying to apply an update. That update fires the trigger, `upd_minsalary_trg`. The trigger in turn calls the package procedure `emp_pkg.set_salary` which itself attempts `select * from jobs`. *That throws the mutating exception*.  A trigger or any code called from it **cannot** access the table that it fires on.  ( BTW there is no work around, your procedure would start the cycle all over again.) **Solution: Drop the trigger.** It is totally unnecessary.

Comment: Procedure `SET_SALARY` looks *strange*. Why are you using a loop? Looping through what, exactly? You're updating `salary` in `EMPLOYEES` table for all jobs equal to `pjobid` parameter value, and then do it as many times as there are rows in `JOBS` table, without actually referencing any value cursor returns. Just remove FOR loop and it *should* be OK.

Comment: You cannot select from the table your trigger is on _during_ the update. At that point oracle does not know what the results is going to be because the table is "MUTATING".

Comment: Why are you trying to do this? Is it a learning exercise? Depending on your requirements, assuming you're not doing this as a learning exercise, a simple view with a min/max aggregate or analytic function would do the trick. (Also, why calculate the min and max separately? You can do this more efficiently by doing them in the same query! And you don't even need separate queries to find the min-max and then do the updates, you can combine them into a single update/merge statement!)

Answer (score 1):

Triggers are a very powerful tool, but there are a couple of limitations, one of which is that you can't select from the table the trigger is on (the dreaded ORA-04091). This limitation makes total sense. There are plenty of articles on google explaining why this error occurs.

There are 2 ways to solve it.

Option 1: avoid the `SELECT ... FROM jobs` in the row level trigger

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JOBS_BIU
AFTER UPDATE OF min_salary ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (new.min_salary != old.min_salary)
BEGIN
  UPDATE employees SET salary = :new.min_salary WHERE job_id = :new.job_id;
END;
/
```

Open 2: Do not use a row level trigger but a statement level trigger. This will fire after the statement has completed:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER JOBS_BIU
AFTER UPDATE OF min_salary ON jobs
BEGIN
  FOR r IN (SELECT * FROM jobs) LOOP
    UPDATE employees
       SET salary = r.min_salary
     WHERE job_id = r.job_id;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: Hi, i don't have any SELECT statements or UPDATE statements on my triggers, what i'm trying to do is after updating the min_salary from the jobs table it will automatically tirgger the procedure hence calling the set_salary. Correct me if I'm wrong but by your statement does that mean that the procedure set_salary is the one causing the mutation?

Comment: Yes, set_salary is causing it. Moving that code to a procedure does not make any difference to the pl/sql engine.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Koen, I got an idea on how to fix my problem so here it is:
First I have updated my jobs package and eliminated all SELECT statement that was being used:
This is my code before:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY jobs_pkg
IS
    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;

    PROCEDURE initialize
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
        LOOP
            jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
        END LOOP;
    END;
   
    FUNCTION get_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
        vmin_salary jobs.min_salary%type;
    BEGIN
        SELECT min_salary
        INTO vmin_salary
        FROM jobs
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
       
        RETURN vmin_salary;
    END get_minsalary;
   
    FUNCTION get_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2)
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS  vmax_salary jobs.max_salary%type;
    BEGIN
        SELECT max_salary
        INTO vmax_salary
        FROM jobs
        WHERE job_id =  jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
       
        RETURN vmax_salary;
    END get_maxsalary;
   
    PROCEDURE set_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmin_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET min_salary = pmin_salary
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
    END set_minsalary;
   
    PROCEDURE set_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmax_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        UPDATE jobs
        SET max_salary = pmax_salary
        WHERE job_id = jobstab(p_jobid).job_id;
    END set_maxsalary;
   
END jobs_pkg;

c. Copy the CHECK_SALARY procedure from Practice 9, Exercise 1a, and modify the code by replacing the query on the JOBS table with statements to set the local minsal and maxsal variables with values from the JOBS_PKG data by calling the appropriate GET_*SALARY functions. This step should eliminate the mutating trigger exception.

CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_salary (pjobid employees.job_id%type, psal employees.salary%type)
IS
    vminsalary  jobs.min_salary%type;
    vmaxsalary  jobs.max_salary%type;
   
BEGIN

    vminsalary := jobs_pkg.get_minsalary(pjobid);
    vmaxsalary := jobs_pkg.get_maxsalary(pjobid);

END check_salary;
```

and this is my code now:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY jobs_pkg
IS

    TYPE jobs_tab_type IS TABLE OF jobs%rowtype INDEX BY jobs.job_id%type;
    jobstab jobs_tab_type;

    PROCEDURE initialize
    IS
    BEGIN
        FOR rec IN (SELECT * FROM jobs)
        LOOP
            jobstab(rec.job_id) := rec;
        END LOOP;
    END;
    
    FUNCTION get_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN jobstab(p_jobid).min_salary;
    END get_minsalary;
    
    FUNCTION get_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN NUMBER
    IS
    BEGIN
        RETURN jobstab(p_jobid).max_salary;
    END get_maxsalary;
    
    PROCEDURE set_minsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmin_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        jobstab(p_jobid).min_salary := pmin_salary;
    END set_minsalary;
    
    PROCEDURE set_maxsalary(p_jobid VARCHAR2, pmax_salary NUMBER)
    IS
    BEGIN
        jobstab(p_jobid).max_salary := pmax_salary;
    END set_maxsalary;
    
END jobs_pkg;
```

Then I removed the `for each row` from my initializer procedure that is found on my jobs package:
From this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER init_jobpkg_trg
BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    jobs_pkg.initialize;
END init_jobpkg_trg;
```

To this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER init_jobpkg_trg
BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON jobs
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('-----Initializing-----');
    jobs_pkg.initialize;
END init_jobpkg_trg;
```

After testing of updaing the min_salary of the jobs table, it all now works :)

Comment: It still automatically update the salary of the employees that is below of the new min_salary on the jobs table thanks to the `set_salary` procedure that is on the emp_pkg.